# Are English 'gay' and Norwegian 'gøy' cognates?

Tags: etymology, germanic-languages, cognates, proto-germanic, norwegian

Norwegian *gøy* means "fun" in both Bokmål and Nynorsk. Does this word have anything to do with English *gay*?

Wiktionary says *gay* comes ultimately from Proto-Germanic *ganhuz* "sudden" via Old French *gai* "joyful, laughing,  merry", but under *ganhuz*, Wiktionary lists no North Germanic descendants.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According [to the Norske Akademis Ordbok](https://www.naob.no/ordbok/g%C3%B8y_1), *gøy* is **from** English “gay”.

Comment: Perplexing way to render it into Nowergian though... I wonder why it's not *gei* or something. The *øy* diphthong is quite distinctive, and its *y* doesn't even sound like English *y*, even aside from the *ø* which is definitely not a close correspondence to the vowel in English. I understand this is an older loan, and maybe there's some vowel sound changes I'm missing, but I can't imagine which.

Comment: @LjL Doesn't seem like too much of a stretch, since the difference between `/ei/` and `/øy/` is only a single feature. Though I also don't know what sound change might have caused it.

Comment: @LjL I think you may be relying too much on the spelling and how the individual vowels of the diphthongs are pronounced outside of the diphthongs. "Gøy" sounds a lot more similar to English "gay" than "gei" would (I'm a native speaker).

Comment: I've also found some material claiming *gøy* as related to English *Guy* (as in Guy Fawkes): the [Swedish Wiktionary](https://sv.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/g%C3%B8y) does that, although I haven't checked the (video?) citation it provides, and then I saw it mentioned on a forum where someone was asking about the word's origin, for the little that's worth. Color me confused as to how Guy Fawkes would semantically turn into *gøy*, but at least in terms of phonetics, to me personally the jump from *Guy* seems less weird than the one from *gay*, although I'm a native speaker of neither language.

Comment: I think [ø] is closer to [e] (in "gay") than [a] (in "Guy"), since [ø] is simply an [e] with rounded lips, while [a] would require moving position __and__ still would need the rounding.

Comment: Cp. PGem [\*gailaz](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/gailaz), Ger *geil*, "cool; horny", "(bot.) stiff, stalky-ing" (v. *[auf]geilen, spargeln*), /ɡaɪ̯l/, sometimes written *goil* (From Austria? As in *alter* > *oida*, En *old*?), also *geilo*, cp. Nl *geil*, /ɣɛi̯l/, En *gole*. It is heavily proscribed, still popular in youth speech; Slav \*gailas and the PIE root are rather negative. I hoped for a Gothic form with /o/ to surface near Gothenburg, but it is not attested. Also Cp. PGem \*gailo; Ger. *gelle; joy, jolly; gag, joke; Gaul; well*; PIE \*gel, "cool"

Comment: @melboiko fair enough, but I guess what I mainly don't get is that Norwegian already has [e] as far as I know, so why not use it to render "gay" if that's what it's rendering?

Comment: @LjL Because there's no diphthong in Norwegian beginning with [e].

Comment: @LjL for all practical purposes the vowel in English `gay` (i.e. the `face` vowel) is a diphthong `/eɪ/` instead of a monophthong `*/e/`, so a Norwegian wouldn't necessarily naturally start with a monophthong `/eː/` to render it. Norwegian orthographic _ei_ is phonologically `/æɪ/`, so that's rather off, and it wouldn't not make sense if Norwegian simply chose to use _øy_ `/œʏ/` for Eng.`/eɪ/`, especially considering rounding for front vowels isn't a thing in English.

Comment: The link refers to https://naob.no/ordbok/ableg%C3%B8y ; you may want to link to https://naob.no/ordbok/g%C3%B8y_2 in addition or instead.

Answer (score 1):

According to Språkrådet's and Universitet i Bergen's ordboka, gøy comes from English 'guy', meaning 'make fun on', from Dutch 'guich', the etymology of which I do not know:

> fra engelsk guy 'gjøre narr av', av nederlandsk guich 'grimase'

Source: https://ordbokene.no/bm,nn/search?q=g%C3%B8y

So there does not seem to be as direct a connection as one could hope for.

Comment: I find this explanation more convincing. The English /ʌ/ vowel often ends up as *ø* in loan words into Norwegian; cf "tøff" from "tough". But I have never heard "guy" in this sense.

Comment: It's familiar to me, though I don't know that I would use it myself. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guy#Verb) (sense 2) gives several quotations.